# Maven dependency with type = pom

Tags: maven, dependencies

I declare in the parent POM

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Further, the child pom use

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

All work fine? but when I use such dependency with type = pom

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
                <version>${jboss-javaee-7.0.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I have error

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project by.services:by.utils:1.0.2 (D:\Work\V2_Change_Maven_Structure\by.utils\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-7.0:jar is missing. @ line 18, column 21
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

How to declare a dependency in dependencyManagement with type = pom
$ {Jboss-javaee-7.0.version} announced
If I bear jboss-javaee-7.0 in the root, then runs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The clarification here is that when you do not define `<type>` on your `</dependency>` within `</dependencyManagement>` it defults to `jar`

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar<type> <!--default value-->
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and hence the `module` uses that jar while using it as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

> The `type` of dependency. This defaults to `jar`. While it usually
> represents the extension on the filename of the dependency, that is not always the case. A type can be mapped to a different extension and a classifier. The type often corresponds to the packaging used, though this is also not always the case.
> Some examples are `jar`, `war`, `ejb-client` and `test-jar`
> New types can be defined by plugins that set `extensions` to `true`, so this is not a complete list.

---

But next when you explicitly declare the parent pom to have the type as

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>${jboss-javaee-7.0.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type><!--override the default value-->
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

the child module now either can inherit the dependency with the same `<type>` as

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
     <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
     <type>pom</type><!--inherited-->
</dependency>
```

OR if you want to utilize the jar of the project which is a different `<type>`, you can explicitly mention the dependency as :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
     <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
     <version>${jboss-javaee-7.0.version}</version>
     <type>jar</type> <!--different from parent-->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to import `jboss-javaee-7.0` jar in your child project, there is no such jar, it is of type pom which you already importing in your parent.

You need to import dependencies of `jboss-javaee-7.0` in your child project, some thing like.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can get more information about [importing dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies)