# How to resolve a Maven dependency of type pom?

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to import a library in Maven which is `Kotlin Multiplatform`.

[This](https://github.com/ajalt/colormath) is it's Github repo (does not actually matter much of course)

Point is, it says it can be imported in with this dependency for Gradle:

```
dependencies {
   implementation("com.github.ajalt.colormath:colormath:2.0.0")
}
```

Obviously, just converting it to `Maven` does not work:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ajalt.colormath</groupId>
            <artifactId>colormath</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

So I added it's pom to the project as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41055309/4420543) explains it:

```xml
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.ajalt.colormath</groupId>
                <artifactId>colormath</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

This dependency is resolved (it can be only resolved as `pom` `type`. Then I add it as `dependency`:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        ...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ajalt.colormath</groupId>
            <artifactId>colormath</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

It still cannot find it.

I also added the `repo1`, because I did not see where `Maven` was looking for this artifact:

```xml
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

But still no success. I don't understand why it's not working.

The code can be found in the [repo1](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/ajalt/colormath/colormath/2.0.0/), but `Maven` does not resolve it.

This must be a very simple thing I am not understanding here, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to the Maven Central from [GitHub](https://github.com/ajalt/colormath) points to a bare POM artifact, without any dependencies and/or attached JARs.

It looks like Kotlin MP uploads JVM-specific artifacts with a different artifactId - `colormath-jvm` in this case. Please check corresponding directory in the [Maven Central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/ajalt/colormath/colormath-jvm/2.0.0).

I suggest using following dependency declaration in the POM:

```
<groupId>com.github.ajalt.colormath</groupId>
<artifactId>colormath-jvm</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
```

Comment: While this works, I need to understand the thought process for fixing this issue - how did you know it must be postfixed with `-jvm`? The `pom.xml` in my original link did not include any info about the url you linked. How did you find it? Was it because you know about `Kotlin Multiplatform` and it's publish process or is this `Maven`-specfic?

Comment: 1. The published artifacts for artifact id colormath contain pom.xml ONLY, no JARs
2. Maven Repository Layout - see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Remote+repository+layout
3. Limited experience with Gradle - enough to know that a pom.xml is constructed by the Maven publishing plugin